# Massive Spring '17 bug: SOQL returns wrong Custom Metadata Type picklist value

Tags: soql, picklist, bug, custom-metadata

Based on all evidence gathered there is a major bug in Spring '17 involving Custom Metadata Types and picklist values: what SOQL returns is different than what's saved in the database.

To reenact:

- go to a sandbox org (where Spring '17 has been activated)
- create a Custom Metadata Type, and add a picklist field with these values:

  - 1
  - 1 or more
  - 2
- add a new entry and put "1 or more" for the picklist value
- open up Developer Console, then run a query against the Custom Metadata Type:

  - `SELECT MyPicklist__c FROM MyCMT__mdt`
  - you will notice the value "2" is returned instead of "1 or more"

Take a look here:

[image]

Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: Do you mean to say, you are filtering by `1 or more` in query and still getting `2`?

Comment: @Ashwani yes. The outcome is the same if I don't have any filters in the query.

Comment: You do not need to run any query. If we can create a view with all columns it can be noticed

Comment: In my case, view itself showing wrong value. I have created a view taking all columns of custom meta data types, it is not taking "1 or more" instead taking 2

Comment: @SantanuBoral you are right. I also managed to get the same results as you with the list view. But the record page shows the correct value.

Comment: I found a new related bug. Delete the picklist value from the field you will still see that value.

Comment: We're looking into this now.

Comment: @AvromRoy-Faderman Is this added to known issues officially?

Comment: @Ashwani, I'm working on getting the known issue added. I believe I've identified a fix and am working towards getting it released.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can track this bug at https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000eshdQAA

It's scheduled to be fixed in the next patch release.

We've identified the exact set of circumstances that cause this to appear. Suppose you have *n* picklist values. If one of those picklist values is a number *m* < *n*, and that value is *not* the *m* th value created, you will see this bug when you try to query for the *m* th value.

For example: The picklist with values "2", "a" will hit this bug (if you create these values as part of creating the picklist), because the *1*st picklist value is *2*. "1", "a" wouldn't have this problem; nor would "a", "2".

In your specific case, it's that the value of the 3rd picklist item is "2", and 3 != 2.

So, while we still regard this as a critical bug for us to fix, it won't impact every picklist.

Comment: Glad to see the people who are working on this stuff monitoring this forum.

Comment: We try. It's not the best way to reach us (probably a case is), but I'm on top of it as much as I can be.

Comment: Indeed. The more channels the better. A lot of folks that surface problems on these forums don't have the ability to open a case, though. It goes both ways and you guys are doing a great job.

Comment: +1 Thanks for explaining the reason. It sounds like, it is affect the alphabets as well? I will have to check my 39 custom metadata types ;(

Comment: It only affects picklists containing entries that are just numbers. The affected entry may be alphabetical, but if you have no numeric entries in a picklist you should be safe. Please let us know if that still causes problems for you; if it does it's a separate issue.

Comment: This is great information! I can now devise a workaround. With a fix on its way this is only going to get better!

Comment: @Mossi If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.